# Static Compliation of Node JS

Tags: node.js, static, glibc

I have build Nodejs Partly static. But when I executed NodeJS in my machine I getting the below error.

## ./node

./node: /lib/ld.so.1: version `GLIBC_2.22' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/tls/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by ./node)

But I have all the libraries in NodeJs Exe Itself. Why it was searching libraries locally?

> -> strings node | grep GLIBC_2 GLIBC_2.2 GLIBC_2.22 GLIBC_2.1 GLIBC_2.0 GLIBC_2.1.3 GLIBC_2.3.2 GLIBC_2.15 GLIBC_2.2.4 GLIBC_2.1.2
>   GLIBC_2.4 GLIBC_2.3 GLIBC_2.3.4 GLIBC_2.7 GLIBC_2.6 GLIBC_2.3.3

Note:
Fully static compliation gives segmentation fault for the same scenario.

Comment: `/lib/ld.so.1` looks very unusual for a glibc system. What exactly are you building?

Comment: Hai ,  My Aim is to build NodeJS with all of the required libraries are statically linked(Which implies it should not searches for libraries in local path). For that I have tried with --partly-static and --fully-static. As result, When NodeJs was build with --partly-static it searches for LIBC library in "/lib/ directory and fully static throws segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps :

Run `apt-get update`

to update the packages database

```
apt-cache policy libc6
```

This will provide you the installed version which can be shown with `ldd --version`

Install the new version with `apt-get install libc6`

Comment: Hai I can't install/upgrade the libc due to some restriction.Is anyother way to overcome the issue.